# Inner Join only if satisfies If condition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How do I minimize the Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetItemCategory]
(               
    @ShopID INT
)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- filter if shopid not equals to 0 
    if @ShopID <> 0

        BEGIN

            SELECT ItemCategory.ItemCategoryID ,CategoryName
            FROM ItemCategory       

            -- join shopitemcategory for filtering      
             inner join ShopitemCategory on             
                   ShopitemCategory.shopid = @ShopID AND            
                   ShopitemCategory.itemcategoryid = ItemCategory.ItemCategoryID

        END

     -- no filter if shopid = 0 
    else

         BEGIN

              SELECT  ItemCategoryID ,CategoryName          
              FROM ItemCategory

         END
 END
```

This works well, but there are other stored procedures that are bigger than this and using same if else method. So is there any way I could simplify this code?

Comment: You can use `PREPARE`

Comment: Personally I wouldn't, The logic seems straightforward , easy to understand and therefore easily maintained.BTW this is sqlserver not mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine in one query as below:

**Solution1:**

`OR` clause in the join

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetItemCategory] (@ShopID INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ItemCategory.ItemCategoryID
        ,CategoryName
    FROM ItemCategory
    INNER JOIN ShopitemCategory ON (
            ShopitemCategory.shopid = @ShopID
            AND ShopitemCategory.itemcategoryid = ItemCategory.ItemCategoryID
            )
        OR (@ShopID = 0)
END
```

**Solution2:**

Use `LEFT JOIN` and added `WHERE` clause:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetItemCategory] (@ShopID INT)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT ItemCategory.ItemCategoryID
            ,CategoryName
        FROM ItemCategory
        LEFT JOIN ShopitemCategory ON
            ShopitemCategory.itemcategoryid = ItemCategory.ItemCategoryID
        WHERE ShopitemCategory.shopid = @ShopID
            OR @ShopID = 0
    END
```

Comment: I dont know why, but when `@ShopID = 0` I am getting duplicate items for several times, not in this query but a bigger query of sametype

Comment: It may due to other joins... If you share the whole query then we can check the exact problem...

Comment: I have added another solution, try that one

Comment: In the second solution why `ON` and `AND` are near ?

Comment: Ok now the duplication problem is removed :) thanks again